# Remove Spaces Between Apostrophe

Tags: sql, oracle, whitespace, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have around 2900 records to be done.

I dont want space between the ' null  ';

My problem:

```
UPDATE  route_table_ex
SET     msg_type = ' null '
WHERE   queue_name = ' DMGGCA5GOPAMSDXMLMSG ';
```

Expected output:

```
UPDATE  route_table_ex
SET     msg_type = 'null'
WHERE   queue_name = 'DMGGCA5GOPAMSDXMLMSG';
```

Comment: I don't get the problem.  Just do `msg_type = 'null'` if you don't want the spaces.  As your question is phrased, *you* are passing in the string constant used for the value.

Comment: Which SQL platform are you using? Microsoft, MySQL, etc.

Comment: oracle Sql developer

Comment: Im using text editor Notepad++ to edit this. What command to use to  find and replace the empty space. '<space> null <space>   '; i want to be like 'null';

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE route_table_ex SET msg_type = LTRIM(RTRIM(' null ')) WHERE queue_name = ' DMGGCA5GOPAMSDXMLMSG';

Comment: the problem when i try to update into sql developer, it doesnt read the with the space '  null  ' & '  DMGGCA5GOPAMSDXMLMSG   ';

Answer (score 0):

To remove the space surrounding the "null", run this:

```
UPDATE  route_table_ex
SET     msg_type = LTRIM(RTRIM(msg_type))
WHERE   queue_name = ' DMGGCA5GOPAMSDXMLMSG ';
```

I am not sure about what you want with the WHERE clause.

If you want to remove all those spaces from both columns, perhaps this is what you want:

```
UPDATE  route_table_ex
SET     msg_type = LTRIM(RTRIM(msg_type)),
        queue_name = LTRIM(RTRIM(queue_name))
```

Comment: the problem when i try to update into sql developer, it doesnt read the with the space ' null ' & ' DMGGCA5GOPAMSDXMLMSG   ';
i have already written the 2900 records into a notepad++.
UPDATE  route_table_ex
SET     msg_type = ' *ALL* '
WHERE   queue_name = ' DMGADSPBBDCHKPTMSG    ';


Is the any way i can replace the empty spaces in notepad++ between the '    *ALL*    ' and the '  DMGADSPBBDCHKPTMSG    ';
i want something like '*ALL*' and the 'DMGADSPBBDCHKPTMSG';
Since i have lots of record to be updated, and sql doesnt accept with the spaces.

Comment: is the any method can be used to replace the empty spaces between the '   null   '. Find what, replace with what. regular expression. something.

Comment: Oh, so your problem is not in the database but in a script you have in a text file? Then what you need is something like doing a "Replace All" of " '" (space + apostrophe) and "' " (apostrophe + space) with `'` (apostrophe) and you should be done. Unless, of course, there are apostrophes inside any of the fields!!

Comment: yes its in a text file. im not sure how to format it accordingly.

Comment: Does the "replace all" of the text editor work for you?

Comment: can giv me an extact command to remove the space '    null    ';   and replace with something like 'null';   for all the cases like tat

Comment: Find what : ?   Replace with : ?  Im using notepad++

Comment: Press `CTRL+H` (or go to Search / Replace), search for space + apostrophe ( '), replace with apostrophe ('), click on "Replace All" once or twice until it tells you that 0 occurrences were replaced. Then search for apostrophe + space (' ), also replace with apostrophe (') and repeat the "Replace All" procedure. It's not rocket science. :P

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or the exact error you are getting? I'm afraid I may not be 100% sure of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL+H (or go to Search / Replace), search for space + apostrophe ( '), replace with apostrophe ('), click on "Replace All" once or twice until it tells you that 0 occurrences were replaced. Then search for apostrophe + space (' ), also replace with apostrophe (') and repeat the "Replace All" procedure.

Comment: You posted my comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851351/remove-spaces-between-apostrophe#comment42266927_26851506) as an answer. Did it finally work?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify, these are (single) ordinary blanks indeed.

If the string should really just read `null` try something like

```
UPDATE  route_table_ex
SET     msg_type = 'null'
WHERE   queue_name LIKE '%DMGGCA5GOPAMSDXMLMSG%';
```

otherwise along

```
UPDATE  route_table_ex
SET     msg_type = REGEXP_REPLACE(msg_type, '[^a-z0-9]', '', 1, 0, 'i')
WHERE   queue_name LIKE '%DMGGCA5GOPAMSDXMLMSG%';
```

In a suitable editor (Notepad++ should actually do.) try regular expressions to fix the data, e.g., search `'.*?null.*?'` and replace with `'null'` or more flexible `'.*?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?'` to `'\1'`.